# Long (or integer) to char(16) in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, casting, entity-framework-6

I need to map a column in a database table that has type char(16) to a field property in an entity (called Number) which is of type Long.

Am getting

> Member Mapping specified is not valid.  The type 'Edm.Int64 of member 'Number' in 'MyEntity' is not compatible with SqlServer.char.

Is there a way to fix this?

I have googled but not seeing any clear answer, from what I have read so far EF struggles with the char type but surely there is a way around this?

I'm using EF NUGET package v6.1.3

Comment: What causes you to map column and field with different types? Any business reason?  You can not change column type to Int or bigint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping a database column of one type to a different type will in your specific case lead to a potential and eventual loss of data.

If you store a value that exceeds the maximum allowed value of the short type, which is equivalent to char(16) in SQL, in your long variable in C# you will not be able to store all that data in the database.

Your application and database will contradict each other and you willingly open up your application to bugs and logical challenges.

It is highly recommended that you ensure that your application's variable type is equivalent to the database column type and vice versa because of the aforementioned reasons.

The fix you are asking for is ensuring that these data types correspond to each other. There is a reason for this exception and that is simply put that long and short are not compatible with each other in this manner. You can store a short value in a long, but you cannot store a long value in a short as that would result in data loss.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was curious more than anything to see if it was possible, the points raised are valid.  I will replace long with string which after testing does work fine

Comment: String? I thought you intended to store numeric data, you previously specified that the name of your column was Number. I do recommend that you make this a numeric datatype, for instance short (for small numbers), int or long (for extra large numbers). I also recommend that you look up these three data types and learn about their minimum and maximum values :)

Comment: I wasn't clear in the question I posed, am not storing the long/integer value directly to the database, just mapping it to a char column (called Number) so I can retrieve a record. This field was setup in an existing database given to me. Yes ideally this should be stored as int/long in the db.

Comment: The functionality for writing back to the db will be exposed no matter what your intention may be.